# import error linearSVR in sklearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I could not import LinearSVR in sklearn. I did the following

```
from sklearn.svm import LinearSVR
```

I can easily import SVR as

```
from sklearn.svm import SVR
```

my sklearn version is `0.15.2`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`LinearSVR` is part of scikit since 0.16, as the [changelog](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/whats_new.html) notes:

> Added svm.LinearSVR. This class uses the liblinear implementation of Support Vector Regression which is much faster for large sample sizes than svm.SVR with linear kernel. By Fabian Pedregosa and Qiang Luo.

Only `sklearn.svm.SVR` is available in 0.15. The documentation offers an overview over all classes in sklearn.svm in 0.15 [here](http://scikit-learn.org/0.15/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.svm).